# How to decompress SHA1[compressed] executable

Tags: unpacking, decompress, delphi

I have struggled a lot to reverse an app that is delphi executable.
So I trusted PEiD to tell me the truth about the app but unfortunately I found these

```
 Nothing found[overlay]*
```

Then I switched the Kanal plugin and it detected crypto signatures

```
  ADLER32
  BASE64
  BZIP2
  CCITT-CRC16[word]
  CRC(rev)
  CRC32
  CRC32b
  CSS [table0]
  FORK-256 [mixing]
  MD5
  SHA1[compress]
  SHA-224[init]
  SHA-256[mixing]
  ZLIB deflate[word]
  {big number}
```

So in my case I never had of these except for Base64

All I need is the app to show its platform in PEiD  and how can I deal with this type of compression?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------this is what iam trying to achieve
this is the onclick event of my two buttons.
i want ESI to be 00000011 before the call @005A6DBD so i tried to change the JNZ @005A6F44 but but ESI becomes 00000018 which is an event of another button.
so as it is now the button(my Target) when i click ESI becomes 00000000 which simply execute the defaut of the Case switch Table that is inside the call @005A6DBD

```
005A6EC4    .  55                PUSH EBP                                  ;  programform buttonclick event
005A6EC5    .  8BEC              MOV EBP,ESP
005A6EC7    .  83C4 F0           ADD ESP,-10
005A6ECA    .  53                PUSH EBX
005A6ECB    .  56                PUSH ESI                                           ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6ECC    .  57                PUSH EDI                                           ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6ECD    .  33C9              XOR ECX,ECX
005A6ECF    .  894D FC           MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],ECX
005A6ED2    .  8BDA              MOV EBX,EDX                                        ;  ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet
005A6ED4    .  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
005A6ED6    .  55                PUSH EBP
005A6ED7    .  68 9C6F5A00       PUSH AcroByte.005A6F9C
005A6EDC    .  64:FF30           PUSH DWORD PTR FS:[EAX]
005A6EDF    .  64:8920           MOV DWORD PTR FS:[EAX],ESP
005A6EE2    .  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
005A6EE4    .  55                PUSH EBP
005A6EE5    .  68 7C6F5A00       PUSH AcroByte.005A6F7C
005A6EEA    .  64:FF30           PUSH DWORD PTR FS:[EAX]
005A6EED    .  64:8920           MOV DWORD PTR FS:[EAX],ESP
005A6EF0    .  C745 F4 0C000000  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C],0C
005A6EF7    .  8BC3              MOV EAX,EBX
005A6EF9    .  8B15 30D24600     MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[46D230]                      ;  AcroByte.0046D288
005A6EFF    .  E8 A8F1E5FF       CALL AcroByte.004060AC
005A6F04    .  8B50 08           MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+8]
005A6F07    .  8D45 FC           LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
005A6F0A    .  E8 D50DE6FF       CALL AcroByte.00407CE4
005A6F0F    .  6945 F4 7C1B0900  IMUL EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C],91B7C
005A6F16    .  8B04C5 08D25F00   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX*8+5FD208]
005A6F1D    .  85C0              TEST EAX,EAX
005A6F1F    .  7C 51             JL SHORT AcroByte.005A6F72
005A6F21    .  40                INC EAX
005A6F22    .  8945 F0           MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10],EAX
005A6F25    .  C745 F8 00000000  MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],0
005A6F2C    .  BB 08D25F00       MOV EBX,AcroByte.005FD208
005A6F31    >  6975 F4 7C1B0900  IMUL ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C],91B7C
005A6F38    .  8B44F3 04         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+ESI*8+4]
005A6F3C    .  8B55 FC           MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
005A6F3F    .  E8 6C17E6FF       CALL AcroByte.004086B0       ;call @UStrEqual( cmp eax,edx inside the call)
005A6F44    .  75 1E             JNZ SHORT AcroByte.005A6F64   ;  this jump
005A6F46    .  8B44F3 08         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+ESI*8+8]
005A6F4A    .  85C0              TEST EAX,EAX
005A6F4C    .  7C 16             JL SHORT AcroByte.005A6F64
005A6F4E    .  40                INC EAX
005A6F4F    .  89C6              MOV ESI,EAX
005A6F51    .  33FF              XOR EDI,EDI                                        ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6F53    >  8BCF              MOV ECX,EDI                                        ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6F55    .  8B55 F8           MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]                       ;  sets the value to EDX(important)
005A6F58    .  8B45 F4           MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C]
005A6F5B    .  E8 E8EFFFFF       CALL AcroByte.005A5F48
005A6F60    .  47                INC EDI                                            ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6F61    .  4E                DEC ESI                                            ;  AcroByte.<ModuleEntryPoint>
005A6F62    .^ 75 EF             JNZ SHORT AcroByte.005A6F53
005A6F64    >  FF45 F8           INC DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]                           ;  AcroByte.015C2BD4
005A6F67    .  81C3 ACB80000     ADD EBX,0B8AC
005A6F6D    .  FF4D F0           DEC DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10]
005A6F70    .^ 75 BF             JNZ SHORT AcroByte.005A6F31
005A6F72    >  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
005A6F74    .  5A                POP EDX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F75    .  59                POP ECX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F76    .  59                POP ECX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F77    .  64:8910           MOV DWORD PTR FS:[EAX],EDX                         ;  ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet
005A6F7A    .  EB 0A             JMP SHORT AcroByte.005A6F86
005A6F7C    .^ E9 CBFCE5FF       JMP AcroByte.00406C4C
005A6F81    .  E8 1E01E6FF       CALL AcroByte.004070A4
005A6F86    >  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
005A6F88    .  5A                POP EDX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F89    .  59                POP ECX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F8A    .  59                POP ECX                                            ;  user32.7500925A
005A6F8B    .  64:8910           MOV DWORD PTR FS:[EAX],EDX                         ;  ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet
005A6F8E    .  68 A36F5A00       PUSH AcroByte.005A6FA3
005A6F93    >  8D45 FC           LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
005A6F96    .  E8 4109E6FF       CALL AcroByte.004078DC
005A6F9B    .  C3                RETN
===========================================================================================================================================================================the folowing is just piece only to show whats happening before the call cause the Whole repeat the same thing


005A6D6D    .  53                PUSH EBX                                           ;  AcroByte.03CA2088
005A6D6E    .  69DA 2B2E0000     IMUL EBX,EDX,2E2B
005A6D74    .  69F8 7C1B0900     IMUL EDI,EAX,91B7C
005A6D7A    .  8D3CFD 08D25F00   LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI*8+5FD208]
005A6D81    .  FF749F 04         PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+EBX*4+4]
005A6D85    .  69DA 2B2E0000     IMUL EBX,EDX,2E2B
005A6D8B    .  69F8 7C1B0900     IMUL EDI,EAX,91B7C
005A6D91    .  8D3CFD 08D25F00   LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI*8+5FD208]
005A6D98    .  8D1C9F            LEA EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+EBX*4]
005A6D9B    .  53                PUSH EBX                                           ;  AcroByte.03CA2088
005A6D9C    .  5B                POP EBX                                            ;  AcroByte.03CA2088
005A6D9D    .  FF74B3 0C         PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+ESI*4+C]
005A6DA1    .  69D2 2B2E0000     IMUL EDX,EDX,2E2B
005A6DA7    .  69C0 7C1B0900     IMUL EAX,EAX,91B7C
005A6DAD    .  8D04C5 08D25F00   LEA EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX*8+5FD208]
005A6DB4    .  8D0490            LEA EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+EDX*4]
005A6DB7    .  8B4CB0 10         MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+ESI*4+10]
005A6DBB    .  5A                POP EDX
005A6DBC    .  58                POP EAX
005A6DBD    .  E8 E6D1FFFF       CALL AcroByte.005A3FA8                             ;  call the function that does the job
005A6DC2    .  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
```

For a better understanding the Call @005A6F3F goes to

```
 Cmp,eax.edx;  Eax=1E37BEE4 Unicode _27,   Edx=1E37B68C Unicode _27
 JE 004086E4;Jumps to retn
 Test eax,edx 
 JE 004086DA; jumps to another bitwise AND
```

That's where I am curious!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanal plugins can provide you with some kind of signature wherever they found it and this means that those crypto signatures are not necessarily useful for your reversing goal.  What are you trying to do exactly?
For Delphi try to use "DeDe" a nice and quite useful Delphi decompiler by DaFixer.

Comment: Thanks but DeDe keeps on thinking and after 2 hours it says out of memory, so I thought it's compressed with Bzip2 maybe. Thank you

Comment: By the way I wanted the onclick event of this app' button to switch to another function and a parameter

Comment: Try give us a disassembly code to see how calls jumps...are ordered and called...

Comment: i have added some code see above

Comment: Have you tried to force ESI to have the value you want ? 
maybe change the line 005A6F31    >  6975 F4 7C1B0900  IMUL ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C],91B7C by "BE 11000000    MOV ESI,11"

Comment: I have tried that and it throws an exception and I think I know why?  I think this is what they call virtualization because Unicode"_27" is the name of the component(button) so why cmp eax,edx while they both have Unicode "_27" and I figured out that the value of edx( 1E37B68C(Unicode "_27)) is the real button and it is the one that puts the value 11 into ESI that's why cmp 1E37BEE4,1E37B68C then jump to return if they are equal. So the Idea will be to locate where EAX get the value(1E37BEE4) and modify it to be (1E37B68C). That's what I thought

Comment: You can dump the value of EAX or see what 1E37BEE4 have as value and try to "mov" it to eax somehere before cmp. where does the program cmp 1E37BEE4,1E37B68C  ?